# VueJS - Multiselect -- Getting errors when trying to implement the basic example

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to implement the very basic example given on their website and my code is below:

```
<template>

     <multiselect v-model="value"
        :options="options"
        :multiple="true"
        :close-on-select="false"
        :clear-on-select="false"
        :hide-selected="true"
        placeholder="Pick some"
        label="name"
        track-by="name">
      </multiselect>

</template>


<script>

import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
components: {
  Multiselect
},
data () {
  return {
    value: [
      { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' }
    ],
    options: [
      { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
      { name: 'Adonis', language: 'JavaScript' },
      { name: 'Rails', language: 'Ruby' },
      { name: 'Sinatra', language: 'Ruby' },
      { name: 'Laravel', language: 'PHP' },
      { name: 'Phoenix', language: 'Elixir' }
    ]
  }
}
}

</script>
```

This is compiling fine, however, when running in the browser, I'm getting the following warnings/errors:

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "key". Expected String, got Boolean.`

`"key" is a reserved attribute and cannot be used as component prop.`

`app.js:964 TypeError: this.$options.filters.filterBy is not a function`

`this.$options.filters.filterBy is not a function`

I don't know what's causing these issues as I'm just using the example that is given on the website.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "babel": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.11.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "vue-multiselect": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.1",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.0.27",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: By a quick look I see you are missing v-model, why? (within your multiselect element)

Comment: @M.Suurland How do you mean? I don't see that, I'm using `<multiselect v-model="value">` here - This is taken directly from the website

Comment: Are you using any props?..

Comment: which version of `vue` are your using? if above 2.0, you may need to update your `vue-multiselect` to 2.0 also

Comment: @Phorce Nevermind, I overlooked it, it is there :)

Comment: @Sabrina Using 2.0 vue but when trying to change vue-multiselect `No compatible version found: vue-multiselect@'>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'`

Comment: I think only  `"vue": "2.1.10"` is compatible https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect/blob/2.0/package.json#L96